# .htaccess it's hiding my folders in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I was making a .htaccess file to run a framework that I was testing, but when I tried to access to my localhost, the folder where is located the framework's files didn't show up.
If I try to access, requesting the `localhost/my_hidden_folder/` this fires a 500 error, internal server error.

This behaviour is result of some wrong configuration with my apache|.htaccess, I'm pretty sure because the same .htaccess in another server works fine.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And here is my default file from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/entrega2>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/unlp>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Both folders, `/var/www/unlp` and `/var/www/entrega2` have the same .htaccess file, and both are hidden.

The most basic redirect in the .htacces file doesn't work, in my localhost, but in the server works. Maybe I have a module disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run phpinfo() to make sure the mod-rewrite is activated.
Create simple php file in your web root folder, which contains:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. You are right the mod_rewrite.so module in  `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` was not enabled. I fix it, running `sudo a2enmod rewrite` this enables the module, also i write in my `httpd.conf` the next line: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a +FollowSymlinks in .htaccess? This usually does the 500 error on Linux systems that have already activated the option or on Windows.

Comment: No, the lines that I have shown above are total of my .htaccess file.